# Why do we use Interface to define the methods and implement and define body of it in Concrete Class?

Tags: java, inheritance, interface

Let me clear my question with an example. Suppose I have an `interface I` in which method `abc()` is defined. I have another two class say `A` and `B` which implements I and override abc() method.

Now my question is why do we user interface just to define the methods and not implemented directly in a class without defining and implementing interface?like...

```
interface I{
    public void abc();
}
class A implements I{
  @Override
  public void abc() { ... }
}
class B implements I{
  @Override
  public void abc() { ... }
}
```

instead of

```
class A {
  public void abc() { ... }
}
class B {
  public void abc() { ... }
}
```

Explaination with small example will be very helpful. Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The advantage of using interface *I* here is:

We can say any object which exposes `abc()` can be put in the same type bucket *I*. So, any object which implements abc() is of type I. We can put this extra information to good use. Its an excellent way of abstraction:

*Any machine with an engine and wheels is a vehicle*

Answer (score 2):

You *can*, if you like, but you won't be able to treat `A` and `B` the same.  There's no way in common to get objects of type `A` and `B` and mix them together, while still being able to call the `abc()` method.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine you have a application which deals with Pets.  You can have many types of pets but they all have the same internal shape and functions.  So when you have a function like getPet() you can return the same interface for Dogs Cats etc.

Once you have the Pet object (might be a Dog or might be a Cat) you can perform the same function E.g. feedPet() which will have different actual code based upon the real Pet.

If you did not adhere to using an Interface you would need different functions for each different Pet.  Imagine the code you would need to change if you wanted to add a new Pet.

Sorry a little contrived but I hope you get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Using interfaces allows for a separation of interface and implementation. Suppose we have another class that depends on the `abc` interface. Encapsulating this function in an interface `I` allows this class to work with multiple implementations of `abc` without having to know (depend on) the specific classes that implement `abc`, leading to a much less coupled and thus more open system.

Note that some languages, e.g. Python, use "duck" typing. Any function that invokes `o.abc()` on an argument could be called with either `A` or `B` without the need for their common interface to be expressed in any other way. Statically typed languages need a different mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the previous answers, if both `A` and `B` will implement method `abc` the same way, you could always think about making `I` an abstract class instead of an interface.  Thus, you get the same benefits of inheritance listed in the other responses with the added bonus of only having to implement the method one time.

Here is an article on using Abstract Classes and Interfaces for further reference:
[Article: JavaWorld](http://www.javaworld.com/javaqa/2001-04/03-qa-0420-abstract.html)